Increasing vs non decreasing
In this video (at this timestamp) Neil Sloane says that the function is increasing, then corrects himself and says "I should say non-decreasing". To me, those both sound the same. Obviously mathematics found a nuance in the difference.
Could someone explain it to me in simple language?

The terminology has changed over the years.  These days "increasing" and "non-decreasing" mean the same thing:  $x>y\implies f(x)≥f(y)$.  In the past, "increasing" meant what we'd now call "strictly increasing", namely:  $x>y\implies f(x)>f(y)$.

@lulu "The years?" The video is 3 years old? (the professor is, admittedly, older)

Yes, but the poster might be older, or might have been taught by someone older.  While I believe the usage I described is fairly standard at the moment, I wouldn't say it was universal.  See, e.g., this post

@lulu I just want an explanation.

And I gave you one.   In the past, "increasing" meant what is now called "strictly increasing" and "non-decreasing" meant what is now called "increasing".  I will not click on the video, but I'll hazard that the speaker is not a young man.

For example:  Consider the sequence $1,2,3,4,5$ versus the sequence $1,2,2,3,4$.  In the past, we would have called the first one increasing and the second one non-decreasing.  That's the usage you are asking about.  Today, however, it would be much more common to call the first one "strictly increasing" and the second one simply "increasing "(or you could still call the second one non-decreasing).

@lulu: Neil Sloane is 84 years old.

@Henry  Exactly.  Thanks!

@Henry  Oh, it's the OEIS man!  Excellent.  Didn't recognize the name.

@lulu only the best of the best, for sequences

There is some ambiguity, to some increasing means strictly increasing, to others is means non decreasing.

The comments under the question regarding the differences between the terms "increasing" and "non-decreasing" function should be enlightening. It is mostly a matter of terminology.
One can think of a non-decreasing function in $\mathbb{R^2}$, as one where at certain intervals the graph of the function might be parallel to the $x-\text{axis}$.
Thus, at such intervals, for example an interval $A$, it holds that $f(x)=c, c\in \mathbb{R}$ $\forall x\in A$ meaning that the function is constant there.
Such a function can have "little steps" between intervals where it is increasing.


Non-decreasing could mean staying at the same amount (i.e. a horizontal line indicating a constant value over time).  So if, while x increases, y always either increases or stays horizontal, the function is non-decreasing.
